# Is it possible to run a bootable image.iso Windows from USB?

Tags: usb, windows

I know it is, but bhat I would like to do is choose which OS to run every time my pc goes on, of course with the USB in. 
I remember my mate's father used to do that at their home

I tried to watch some videos, but honestly..each guy makes it in their way...so can someone help ?

Comment: There's no such thing as a live Windows environment. (Well, technically there's Windows To Go, but you need an Enterprise license to use it)

Comment: As I said, I've watched some videos, and they do it (but don't know how they choose which os to run

Answer (score 1):

Is it acceptable for you to have Windows on the internal HDD and other OS on USB, so that grub on the USB gives option to boot OS on USB or Windows on HDD?

If so give mkusb a try, there is a grub option to boot internal drive or USB.

In the old days it was possible to install and boot Windows XP from flash drive using the Ngine method:

http://tdoui.webs.com/Install%20And%20Run%20Windwos%20XP%20From%20USB.pdf .

WinUSB and it's forks claimed to be able to run later versions of Windows from USB but I have not heard of anyone having success using it. There are for money Windows to USB tools out there many of which look like scams.

Windows To Go will allow running later versions of Windows off of flash drive but only as a installation, not as an ISO file. I have not heard of anyone dual booting with a WTG install.

You can install Windows to VBox on USB, (it is slow for me even using USB3 and it runs as a VDI file and not as an ISO).

I have had most success using VBox with a Full Ubuntu install to USB rather than a Persistent install. With a Persistent install I eventually got corruption in the casper-rw partition and fragmentation in the NTFS partition, (it took about 6 months to happen).

Comment: I think that in the long run an *installed Ubuntu system (with VBox with Windows) is more stable* for this kind of task compared to a persistent live system. Both systems are portable, but the persistent live system is more portable.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows in VirtualBox in Ubuntu in USB

You can install Ubuntu *persistent live* or as an *installed system* into a USB pendrive or external box. **In Ubuntu you can install VirtualBox and in VirtualBox you can install Windows.** I have such an *installed* Ubuntu system in an SSD in an external box, and it works well.

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

It is important to *backup* the system regularly in order to get it back, if it gets corrupted, because the connection via USB makes it more sensitive.

Comment: I tried with VirtualBox, but it was not possible to me to connect to the Internet..

Comment: Internet connection for Windows 10 should be possible to fix. It works for me 'out of the box' with the VirtualBox version from the Ubuntu repositories without fixing anything in an installed Ubuntu (installed from a 16.04.1 LTS 64-bit iso file). I did fix the USB connection with the Extension Pack.

Comment: If the VBox host is able to get Internet the guest should be able to get it also. There should be an icon at the lower right side of the VBox screen that indicates activity of network interfaces, confirm that this shows "cable connected" and is not greyed out.