# Can I use a bootable pen drive to store data other than Linux OS?

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive

Can I use a bootable pen drive to store data other than Linux OS?
I have this pen drive

[Sandisk Cruzer Blade](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B005FYNT3G/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_image_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Comment: You can format it to `FAT32` and use it anywhere.

Comment: Yes you can, however if you refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, you'll note only Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: You can use [Ventoy](https://ventoy.net)

Comment: @lucki1000 Ventoy used exFAT. Older versions of Ubuntu need an add on to use exFAT.

Comment: Ubuntu is a Linux OS.

Comment: Ventoy can also use NTFS and Ext4, my private stick used ext4 and my office stick uses NTFS to access it under windows. @C.S.Cameron

Answer (score 2):

## Different bootable USB drives

Maybe the most convenient way to get what you want is

- a persistent live drive or
- an installed system in a USB drive (installed like into an internal drive, but in this case to a pendrive).

You can also have a live-only drive with part of the drive for storage.

**Edit:** The Sandisk Cruzer Blade series are reliable but slow USB pendrives. I would not recommend an installed system, but rather a persistent live or live-only system with a partition for data storage on that kind of drive. I would also recommend an Ubuntu flavour with a light desktop environment (Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu).

## See these links:

#### About file systems

- [How do I copy a file larger than 4GB to a USB flash drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952673/how-do-i-copy-a-file-larger-than-4gb-to-a-usb-flash-drive/952706#952706)

#### About bootable external drives

- [How is it easier to make a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10)
- [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)
- [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step)
- [Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS)
- [Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)
- [How to install applications in ubuntu while using live persistance usb?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251217/how-to-install-applications-in-ubuntu-while-using-live-persistance-usb)
- [Live USB with persistence vs full install on USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330368/live-usb-with-persistence-vs-full-install-on-usb)

Comment: Can you suggest drives that are in india

Comment: @DashingDojo, I'm sorry, I live in Sweden, and don't know the Indian market. Let us hope that somebody, who knows the market will chip in and help you. You can also ask in the [Ubuntu Forum for hardware](https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=332).